# Grunt-contrib-sass for dev and prod?

Tags: sass, gruntjs

How set up different tasks of grunt-contrid-sass for dev and prod?
I need different css-files - with and without sourcemaps.

I tried:

```
sass: {
dev: {
    options: {
        sourcemap: 'inline',
    },      
},      
prod: {
    options: {
        sourcemap: 'none',
    },      
},
      files: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'static/compass/sass/pages/redesign/',
        src: ['**/*.scss'],
        dest: 'static/compass/css/pages/redesign/',
        ext: '.css'
      },
  },
```

But in this case sass:dev task doesn't compile any files.

When I try:

```
sass: {
dev: {
    options: {
        sourcemap: 'inline',
    },      
      files: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'static/compass/sass/pages/redesign/',
        src: ['**/*.scss'],
        dest: 'static/compass/css/pages/redesign/',
        ext: '.css'
      },

},      
prod: {
    options: {
        sourcemap: 'none',
    },      
      files: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'static/compass/sass/pages/redesign/',
        src: ['**/*.scss'],
        dest: 'static/compass/css/pages/redesign/',
        ext: '.css'
      },

},
  }
```

I get a warning with suggestion to use "--force". But even with using "--force" I get no compiled files.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second example is close to what it should be. However the value of each `files` property should be an Array which contains an Object as shown in [this example](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass#compile-files-in-a-directory) in the docs.

For instance, it should be:

```js
files: [{
  //...
}]
```

and *NOT*:

```
files: {
  //...
}
```

Change your `saas` task to the following instead:

```js
sass: {
  dev: {
    options: {
      sourcemap: 'inline'
    },      
    files: [{ // <-- change this
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'static/compass/sass/pages/redesign/',
      src: ['**/*.scss'],
      dest: 'static/compass/css/pages/redesign/',
      ext: '.css'
    }] // <-- change this
  },
  prod: {
    options: {
      sourcemap: 'none'
    },      
    files: [{ // <-- change this
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'static/compass/sass/pages/redesign/',
      src: ['**/*.scss'],
      dest: 'static/compass/css/pages/redesign/',
      ext: '.css'
    }] // <-- change this
  }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

**Note:** You should also consider changing your `dest` path in either the `dev` or `prod` targets (or both) because currently they are the same path, i.e. if you run both `sass:prod` and `sass:dev` the output from one task will overwritten by the other.

Comment: Thank you very much! Works perfectly.